# Getting a data to display in a DataGridView using a combobox to filter the results of the queries

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview, combobox

My group is having trouble getting this combobox and datagridview to talk to each other. What is supposed to happen is that when you select a name from the combobox, any open incidents with a tech id attached are supposed to appear. We've got the filters working but we can't seem to get the two to talk to one another. Here's the code we have so far:

```
public partial class frmIncidentMaintenance : Form
{
    public Incident incident;
    public frmIncidentMaintenance()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TechSupportEntities techSupport = new TechSupportEntities();

            var customers = (from customer in techSupport.Customers
                            orderby customer.Name
                            select new { customer.CustomerID, customer.Name 
   }).Distinct();
        cmbCustomersBindingSource.DataSource = customers.ToList();
        cmbCustomersBindingSource.DisplayMember = "Name";
        cmbCustomersBindingSource.ValueMember = "CustomerID";





        var products = from customer in techSupport.Customers
                       from incident in customer.Incidents
                       where incident.TechID != null
                       where incident.DateClosed == null
                       select new
                       {
                           incident.ProductCode,
                           incident.TechID,
                           incident.Title,
                           incident.DateOpened,
                           incident.DateClosed,
                           incident.Description
                       };


        dataGridView1.DataSource = products.ToList();


    }

    private void cmbCustomers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs 
e)
    {                  




    }

    private void dataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, 
DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to put some logic at cmbCustomers_SelectedIndexChanged, for example, make a method that receives a parameter (cmbCustomers SelectedValue), and then call it every time the cmbCustomers fires the event.

Comment: Like what exactly JCM? Me and my two partners have been working on this for two weeks and we keep getting stuck at the SelectedIndexChanged event handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void cmbCustomers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs 
e)
{          
     //This is the string for your tech id 
     string tech_id = combobox.SelectedItem.ToString();

     //Searches the datagridview
     int rowIndex =0;
     foreach(DataGridViewRow row in [name of grid here])
     {
        //matches tech-id to gridrow value
        if(tech_id == row.Cells[//Cell for tech_id].Value.ToString())
        {
            //Looks for open incidents (ill guess a numberical value 1 or 0
            int open_close_value = Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells[openvalue]contains this data].value.ToString());
            if(open_close_value == value your looking for)
            {
                //rowindex will give you the row of the gridview
                rowindex = row.Index;
                string incident = row.Cells[you incident].Value.ToString();

                // for pushing data to be displayed in textboxes make it
                // easier on yourself and allow the search engine to pull 
                //all incidents that are open with that tech_id add them to a list
                //this will add the row number plus the incident 
                Listbox1.Items.Add(rowindex+","+incident);

                //now on listbox1 selectedindex change all you do is parse rowindex, and use that rownumber to pull data out of database.
                // your parse string should look like this. 
              //string[] data = listbox1.Selectedindex.ToString().Split(new string[] {","}, StringSplitOptions.None);
              //to get data from gridview
              //string incident= yourGrid.Rows[data[0]].Cell[the cell you want].value.ToString();












}
```

Comment: This will pull all know open incidents for a tech id, and allow you to select one from a list. to display. Hope it helps you out.

Comment: Is there anyway to display that same info in a DataGridView, Michael? We want to be able to change info in certain columns.

Comment: Declare your variables to be added to your grid. then use  GridName.Rows.Add(// variable1, variable2);     Place your variable in order of the columns of the grid. Meaning, if product is in column 0, then when adding a  row it is the first variable. Column 1 would be the second Column. And So on.

Comment: instead of add variables call it directly. newGrid.Rows.Add(row.Cells[0].value, row.Cells[1].value);                                                    the commas seperate cells of the row.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void cmbCustomers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
 //This is the string for your tech id 
 string tech_id = combobox.SelectedItem.ToString();

 //Searches the datagridview

 foreach(DataGridViewRow row in [name of grid here])
 {
    //matches tech-id to gridrow value
    if(tech_id == row.Cells[//Cell for tech_id].Value.ToString())
    {
        //Looks for open incidents (ill guess a numberical value 1 or 0
        int open_close_value = Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells[openvalue]contains this data].value.ToString());
        if(open_close_value == value your looking for)
        {
            //rowindex will give you the row of the gridview
            rowindex = row.Index;
            string incident = row.Cells[you incident].Value.ToString();

            // for pushing data to be displayed in textboxes make it
            // easier on yourself and allow the search engine to pull 
            //all incidents that are open with that tech_id add them to a grid
            //this will add the row number plus the incident 
            NewGrid.Rows.Add(row.Cells[0].Value, row.Cells[1].Value,row.Cells[2].Value, row.Cells[3].Value,row.Cells[4].Value,row.Cells[5].value);

            //now on listbox1 selectedindex change all you do is parse rowindex, and use that rownumber to pull data out of database.
            // your parse string should look like this. 
          //string[] data = listbox1.Selectedindex.ToString().Split(new string[] {","}, StringSplitOptions.None);
          //to get data from gridview
          //string incident= yourGrid.Rows[data[0]].Cell[the cell you want].value.ToString();



}
```

Comment: this will add to a seperate gridview